# Calculating the distance from one point to every other point in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the below code which will calculate the distance between any two points using Google maps api.

Code:

```
def calculateDistance(sourceLatitude, sourceLongitude, destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude):
        sourceCoordinates = sourceLatitude, sourceLongitude
        destinationCoordinates = destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude

        url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins={0}&destinations={1}&mode=driving&language=en-EN&sensor=false".format(str(sourceCoordinates),str(destinationCoordinates))
        result= simplejson.load(urllib.urlopen(url))
        resulting_distance = result['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text']
        print "The distance is: " + resulting_distance
```

I have a TSV file as shown below:

```
Longitude    Latitude

-4.143452    5.342044
-3.913602    5.341612
-3.967045    5.263331

...          ...
...          ...
```

I have a below method which reads the TSV

```
def readTSV():
    with open('TSVFile.txt','r') as f:
    myList = zip(*(line.strip().split('\t') for line in f))
```

Now, the List "myList", contains all the values from the tsv file into the list.

My question is how do i pass these list of values to the "**calculateDistance**" method, in such a way that every combination of the values in the list are covered? To be more precise, i need to calculate the distance from one point to every other point in the list.

Comment: You could have a look at [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

Comment: Why don't you read through the documentation, and experiment with the implementation in the interpreter? This isn't a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use list comprehension:

```
distances = [[calculateDistance(sLa, sLo, dLa, dLo) for (dLa, dLo) in myList] for (sLa, sLo) in myList]
```

Here is the result using Manhattan distance:

```
>>> myList = [(1,1),(3,2),(5,1)]
>>> def calculateDistance(a,b,c,d):
...   return abs(a-c)+abs(b-d)
...
>>> [[calculateDistance(sLa, sLo, dLa, dLo) for (dLa, dLo) in myList] for (sLa, sLo) in myList]
[[0, 3, 4], [3, 0, 3], [4, 3, 0]]
```